# RecyclerView inside ViewPager Fragment don't show

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

So i have a fragment, which have a viewpager with tablayout, which consist of two tabs-two fragments.

The thing is, recyclerview shows empty, and i have no idea why.,

Tab Fragment LAyout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Tag Fragment:

```
List<OrderListItem> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
        orderList.add(new OrderListItem(333, "ABCDE", new Date(), new Date(), false, true));

        adapter = new OrderListAdapter(orderList, this.getActivity());
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Adapter:

```
public class OrderListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<OrderListItem> orderList;
    @LayoutRes
    private final int layoutRes;

    private Context context;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public OrderListAdapter(List<OrderListItem> orderList, Context context){
        this.orderList = orderList;
        this.layoutRes = R.layout.order_list_item_layout;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final OrderListItem item = orderList.get(position);    
    }

    public void setItems(List<OrderListItem> orderList){
        this.orderList.clear();
        this.orderList.addAll(orderList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return orderList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

        }
    }
}
```

RecycleView Item some colorful layouts insider, so i know if the child layout is there or not, which it isnt. any idea why recyclerview is empty?

edit1: i know the recyclerview is there, because its in a lolipop phone, and if i make a movement at the recycler place it shows me the ripple top and bottom scroll border. but the child layouts are empty and blank, and should be colorful as i specificed in the child layout.

eit2. just used a listview with a simpleAdapter and it is showing. there must be something buggy with the rv

edit3: row layout (i should clearly see an empty textview with a color, besides not any value setted.)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_200"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the logic in which you set `OrderListItem` properties to ui?
You have first to set ViewHolder components:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mTitleTv;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_id_in_your_xml_file);
    }
}
```

And then set them in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final OrderListItem item = orderList.get(position);   
    holder.mTitleTv.setText(item.getReplaceThisWithAStringProperty);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you have to use default `LinearLayoutManager` properties use this constructor:

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

Instead of this:

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
```

Add also fixed size property for RecyclerView:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize = true;
```

Comment: i didn't yet, because i couldn't set the child items to show.  My child item layout has some colors so i know if its displayed. At the moment is not setting anything, but that is not the point, if if it was, it wud still not show

Comment: @user3806331 post your xml file for cell

Comment: done. I know i didn't set any value, but the textview color is there so i can check if its showing or not

Comment: the fragment containing the recyclerview is a viewpager fragment of some tab, which is hosted inside a fragment. i think the problem has something to do with that. iv used recyclerview multipletime and didn't have any problem. or im just missing something stupied. @Fondesa

Comment: layoutmanager and fixedsize corrected but still showing blank. Also, after creating the adapter, initiating the list and setting it to the rv, iv printed adapter.getItemCount() and the items are there. just dont appear @Fondesa

Comment: @user3806331 Did you got any solution for this issue ? Please comment here to let me know

Comment: This worked for me.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579614/how-to-implement-recyclerview-in-a-fragment-with-tablayout

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="50dp"  // set yourself
android:layout_height="50dp" // set yourself
```