# How to implement a listview in a SlidingTab?

Tags: android, listview, android-sliding

I'm having trouble on how to implement a listview to a fragment in a slidingtab. I'm still a novice in Android and have tried many tutorials but all they have is how to create a slidingtab whose pager contains textview instead of a listview (though I have managed to try changing the textview from my layout into a listview which work well but am having trouble on how to implement them in Java).

There are even some tutorials that taught about tablayout which appears to be good but unfortunately they are deprecated now so the only thing that's left is the sliding tab. So I'd like to ask for some sites or any guide.

This is the tutorial that I've followed and successfully run, you can see the codes there:
http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-sliding-tabs-example/

So far this is the only well-made tutorial video that shows how to create tabs with listview but unfortunately some codes are now deprecated.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2mMwWiZBmE

By the way the listview that I'm asking contains listitems that are:

1. countable in array like this:

   ```
   String tabs[]={"languages","my notes"};
   ```
2. the other one is fetch from a database which is SQLite or JSON I think.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579614/how-to-implement-recyclerview-in-a-fragment-with-tablayout

Comment: @DanielNugent based on the link you've given me does that mean the i have to create everything from scratch again and not used the tutorial link from manishkpr:webheavens.com? Anyway thanks for the suggestion.