# Android Tabbed layout

Tags: android, mobile, tabbed-view

This thread was probably raised many, many times, but i still haven't found any solution how to create simple tabbed layout, like Google Play app got one, which could work for me (deprecated classes/functions, or i receive errors which i couldn't understand).
Can someone please answer me with some links maybe or short explaination?
As far a i understand, i need actionBar in my mainActivity and 2 seperate activities (i want only 2 tabs, its training only) which are active at the same time. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: You need to use Fragments with tabs these days, with a TabLayout from the support library, see here for a complete example: [How to implement RecyclerView in a Fragment with TabLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579614/how-to-implement-recyclerview-in-a-fragment-with-tablayout)

Comment: This is not a tutorial site. Google will be your best friend during these difficult times. When you begin to write some code and have a specific question regarding code, that's where we're here to help.