# android PagerTabStrip to start from left and not center

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-xml, pagertabstrip

i have a pager tab strip in my project and when run on emulator or device it starts center like this

[image]

what i would like to achieve is to have the tab start left like this

[image]

I have tried layout graviity left in my xml but this is not working for me and i can't put my finger on how to resolve this, here is my xml with the pager tab strip.

```js
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/tab_strip"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false">



        </android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip>


</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>




</LinearLayout>
```

java code

```js
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    //adview


    ViewPager pager;
PagerTabStrip tab_strp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_tab);
        ma_pager_adapter mapager=new ma_pager_adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(mapager);
tab_strp=(PagerTabStrip)findViewById(R.id.tab_strip);
tab_strp.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

     //   tab_strp.setTextSize(14,14);
       // tab_strp.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.WHITE);

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.firsteps);
        mp.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            ImageView welcomeText = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btsMainTextImage);
            //welcomeText.animate().rotation(1440f).setDuration(2000);


        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.share) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }




}
```

```js
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


import java.util.Locale;


//final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.short_whoosh2);

    public ma_pager_adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);


    }
   //final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.short_whoosh2);



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                tab1 t1 = new tab1();
                return t1;
            case 1:
                tab2 t2 = new tab2();
                return t2;
            case 2:
                tab4 t4 = new tab4();
                return t4;
            case 3:
                tab3 t3 = new tab3();
                return t3;
            case 4:
                tab5 t5 = new tab5();
                return t5;

        }
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }//set the number of tabs





    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                return "Tab1";
            case 1:

                return "Tab2";
            case 2:

               return "Tab3";

            case 3:

                return "Tab4";

            case 4:

                return "Tab5";

        }
        return null;
    }



}
```

Comment: post your java code here.

Comment: one moment i shall add java code

Comment: Use a TabLayout, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34581086/4409409

Comment: @DavidMarsh where is your `SlidingTabLayout` define code .

Comment: Make width to _match_parent_ for _PagerTabStrip_

Comment: updated and added more java

Comment: my current app i am building is almost built up, would it be an easy change to replace with SlidingTabLayout

Comment: and my mininmum sdkversion is api 14

Comment: @Ironman that tutorial is way outdated.  There is no need to use a third party library for tabs anymore, since the TabLayout class has been added to the support library.

Comment: @DanielNugent I will be using TabLayout, just hope i can update my apps code and xml without getting in a mess,i still have lots to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible with PagerTabStrip and ToolBar. Since ActionBarTabs have been deprecated, use a TabLayout.

Comment: @DanielNugent TabLayout is the correct answer it seems, and by using this has solved my problem, thank you

Comment: TabLayout is really wokring good. It has many features then PagerTabStrip.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code that how you can use TabLayout easily.

Here is the output that you will get. 
[image]

**main_activty.xml** or any of your XML file where your want to use these Tabs and Viewpager

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="#f9f8f8"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fff"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">


</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

That XML code should work for you. For the complete code, you can visit here - https://tutorialvilla.com/how/how-to-use-tablayout-and-viewpager-in-android-kotlin