# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm trying to add Tabhost to my app, but for some reason when i run the app it gives me this earror **java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TabHost**.

**here is the full exception**:

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process:     com.world.bolandian.tests, PID: 4159
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.world.bolandian.tests/com.world.bolandian.tests.TabHostMain}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TabHost
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TabHost
     at android.app.TabActivity.onContentChanged(TabActivity.java:128)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:391)
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2188)
     at com.world.bolandian.tests.TabHostMain.onCreate(TabHostMain.java:15)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

**this is the XML of the activity EDITED**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.world.bolandian.tests.TabHostMain"
   android:id="@+id/tabHost"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/GPS"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**Activity code**

```
   public class TabHostMain extends TabActivity {

   TabHost tabHost;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_host_main);


    tabHost = getTabHost();

    TabHost.TabSpec ts1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("main");
    ts1.setIndicator("Main");
    ts1.setContent(new Intent(this, Main.class));
    tabHost.addTab(ts1);

    TabHost.TabSpec ts2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("GPS");
    ts2.setIndicator("GPS");
    ts2.setContent(new Intent(this, GPS.class));
    tabHost.addTab(ts2);


    TabHost.TabSpec ts3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Info");
    ts3.setIndicator("Info");
    ts3.setContent(new Intent(this, Info.class));
    tabHost.addTab(ts3);

   }
 }
```

Comment: you might be trying to cast another layout id  which is relative layout.  (may be with similar id with tabhost?)

Comment: Show your `onCreate()` method in TabHostMain.java, and show where line 15 is in there.....

Comment: sorry guys, here i uploaded the java code

Comment: got removed by the other edit

Comment: A very important thing to note is that [TabActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) was deprecated in api level 13, and we are now on api-23.  So, this is ancient stuff here.  These days you should be using a TabLayout from the support library, take a look at this answer for an example of how to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34581086/4409409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `xml` file, the id for the `TabHost` should be `android:id="@android:id/tabhost"`:

So change your xml file to implement this change.

> Btw `TabActivity` is now depricated and you should use it like [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) now.

**UPDATE**

Your `xml` file should look something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.world.bolandian.tests.TabHostMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/GPS"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/Info"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
         </FrameLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: what do you mean by change my xmi file to implement it?

Comment: your topmost markup is a `RelativeLayout` currently, right? it should be `TabHost`. So, I mean change this.

Comment: you can checkout this tutorial on `TabActivity` for better understanding on how to implement a `TabActivity` : http://androidrises.blogspot.in/2012/10/tabactivity-example.html

Comment: thanks my friend, im checking it. so what i should change in the XML is the RelativeLayout to "TabHost"?

Comment: i changed it to TabHost but still giving me the same error

Comment: please update your question with the latest xml code, also checkout the above tutorial for anything that you're missing.

Comment: I have edited my XML fille and also looked on the tutorial. i did exactly like in the tutorial, but still not working...

Comment: is the error still same `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TabHost` ?

Comment: ok found the error in your code finally, your id should be `tabhost`, change that from `tabHost` and it will work!

Comment: also, write the id like this : `android:id="@android:id/tabhost"` instead of `android:id="@+id/tabhost"`

Comment: getTabHost() method looks for  a `TabHost` here `android.R.id.tabhost` but setting `+id/tabhost` will result in `R.id.tabHost`

Comment: also note that `TabActivity` is now depricated and you should avoid using it if possible or use it like this : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html