# Android Recycler View in tab layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-pageradapter

I'm trying to set up a tablayout with 3 tabs, each tab will have a recycler view in it. I found this question: [How to implement RecyclerView with CardView rows in a Fragment with TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579614/how-to-implement-recyclerview-in-a-fragment-with-tablayout)
Which is similier to what I want, I'm trying to set this up, then I'll set up my data retrieval after I get this working.

The problem I'm getting now it setting up the PagerAdapter. Here is my code:

```
public class WorkoutDaysActivity extends BaseActivity{

ListView mListView = new ListView(this);
ArrayList<CustomObject> w29w1m;
CustomListViewAdapter mCustomListViewAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workout_days);
    mToolBar = activateToolbar();
    setUpNavigationDrawer();

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter =
            new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), WorkoutDaysActivity.this)

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }

}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab One", "Tab Two", "Tab Three" };
    Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentPagerAdapter fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new WorkoutDetailFragment();
            case 1:
                return new WorkoutDetailFragment();
            case 2:
                return new WorkoutDetailFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        View tab = LayoutInflater.from(WorkoutDaysActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
        tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
        return tab;
    }

}}
```

The first spot where I'm getting an error is

```
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter =
            new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), WorkoutDaysActivity.this)

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

The error is:

```
 PagerAdapter (android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter, Context) in PagerAdapter cannot be applied to: (android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, WorkoutDaysActivity.this)
```

The android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager is the part underlined in red. The second error is in this part:

```
class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab One", "Tab Two", "Tab Three" };
    Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentPagerAdapter fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }
```

The error is in the super(fm); part, and it states:

```
FragmentPagerAdapter (android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager) in FragmentPagerAdapter cannot be applied to: android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
```

I feel like this would be a simple error with importing the wrong thing, but my attempts to fix it failed. Any help greatly appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PagerAdapter class extends FragmentPagerAdapter. Then its constructor TAKES a FragmentPagerAdapter to initialize. So to initialize a FragmentPagerAdapter you need a FragmentPagerAdapter already?

I think that parameter is supposed to be a FragmentManager.