# Card View inside a fragment

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android application in which there is a tabular view to swipe through fragments. I want to set up a card view in one of the fragments. I am able to implement in a new activity but I am not able to implement it inside a fragment. I am not able to use functions like findViewById() and setContentView()

PS: I tried setting it up using "this" and getActivity() but it still isn't working.

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: The code is very confidential to be posted. I'm not able to access findViewbyId() i.e. application crashes

Comment: Please guys don't downvote the question, I am badly stuck at this

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34581086

Comment: First read about fragment and activity communication!

Comment: @PrashantNegi Post that code, exclude all the confidential details. we cant help you without the code.

Comment: This is to let you know that your question is being down-voted just because your question does not show efforts or you did not upload required code,so that SO community could help you.Please improve your question.

Comment: @PrashantNegi read the on-hold message above, including the link, to find out why your question was downvoted. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also follow the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access your code like below in **oncreateView** method.

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YourLayout, container, false);

        cardView=(CardView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

    return rootView;
```

SetContentView() is where you directly pass your view but in fragment you have to inflate layout using inflater provided in `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)`  function. For more info read [official doc.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: Thanks Preetika it worked. But i dont get why people are diownvoting this question. Thanks for your help again

Comment: Its ok I dont knoe why but someone downvoted my answer as well...When they find something not useful they downvote it... but glad to help you