# How to remove ActionBar from loading in between TabBar and ToolBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I think that's the ActionBar that appears between the TabBar and ToolBar, it's not supposed to happen. How do I remove the ActionBar from the middle without affecting the settings button from working?

[image]

Here's my XML file for this ToolBar/TabBar:

[image]

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml if needed:

[image]

I think the ActionBar is being loaded in between the TabBar and ToolBar but how do I remove it from appearing there without entering NoActionBar in styles.xml? If I do "NoActionBar" in styles.xml then Settings don't work.

I'm not 100% certain it's an action bar. It can also be something else but I need to get rid of it.

This is the error I receive when I put "NoActionBar" in styles.xml and build/run the app.

The highlighted red error:

```
     URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)
```

[image]

Comment: Use a NoActionBar theme, and set the Toolbar as the ActionBar using `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)`   See here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34581086/4409409

Comment: I did this already previously. When you set "NoActionBar" then in styles.xml  and use setSupportActionBar(Toolbar), the app crashes because it can't have "NoActionBar" in styles.xml

Comment: @iBEK this supposed to be the right way to go. Can you post the crash log?

Comment: I don't have a crash, I can't even use "NoActionBar". It tells me "Cannot resolve symbol 'Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar".  Validates resource reference inside Android XML file

Comment: I'll include the error above that I receive when I build/run the project with this above "cannon resolve symbol" crash.