# Is this bug related to Recycler View setup? How can I resolve it?

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

The screenshot of the emulator is attached below.

Initially when the application is run is setup ,the layout gets distorted .

Only after scrolling the items get layout properly .

It seems as if only after the view has been recycled, the position of the items are known . How can i resolve such an issue?

I would be really glad if anyone can help me out.Also where can i find examples of recycler view implementation.

[Initial view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inmhE.png)

[After scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0blBw.png)

RecyclerViewAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        ArrayList<RecyclerViewClass1> mItems;
        Context mContext;

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext,ArrayList<RecyclerViewClass1> mItems ) {
            this.mItems = mItems;
            this.mContext = mContext;
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                    .inflate(R.layout.topfrag11, parent, false);


            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            holder.binddata(mItems.get(position));
        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mItems.size();
        }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mtext2, mtext3;
        //public LinearLayout mLL2;
        public TextView mtext1,mtext6;
        //public LinearLayout mLL1;
        public TextView mtext4, mtext5;
        //public LinearLayout mLL3;

        private Context mContext;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            mtext2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            mtext3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            //mLL2 = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.LL2);

            mtext1 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            mtext6 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);

            //mLL1 = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.LL1);

            mtext4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            mtext5 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);

            //mLL3 = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.LL3);

            //mContext = itemView.getContext();

        }

        public void binddata(RecyclerViewClass1 recyclerViewClass1)
        {
            mtext1.setText(recyclerViewClass1.getText1());
            mtext2.setText(recyclerViewClass1.getText2());
            mtext3.setText(recyclerViewClass1.getText3());
            mtext4.setText(recyclerViewClass1.getText4());
            mtext5.setText(recyclerViewClass1.getText5());
            mtext6.setText(recyclerViewClass1.getText6());


        }
    }

}
```

this is how i am setting it up

```
    public class topfragtab1 extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";

   // private RecyclerView mRecyclerView ;
    //private RecyclerViewAdapter mRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private ArrayList<RecyclerViewClass1> mItems;
    //private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mlayoutManager;
    //Context mContext;
    //FavEditBtnRVA adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.topfrag1,container,false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
        //mContext = this.getContext();

        //adapter = new FavEditBtnRVA();
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.editbtn);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent openeditfav = new Intent(getActivity(),faveditbtn.class);
                startActivity(openeditfav);
            }
        });

        mItems = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            mItems.add(new RecyclerViewClass1(i+"string1",i+"string2",i+"string3",i+"string4",i+"string5",i+"string6"));

        }



        RecyclerViewAdapter mRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),mItems);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        return view;
    }



}
```

XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/editbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_floatedit"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It's good that you have posted your adapter code, but it would help if you would also post the code that sets up the `RecyclerView`. Your issue may be in that code.

Comment: @Cheticamp I have added the adapter setup code.please have a lookup.

Comment: This may be a timing issue with layout. Try moving the `RecyclerView` setup to a later life cycle method such as `onViewCreated` or `onActivityCreated`. The will ensure that the `ViewGroup` is sized and laid out before the layout manager goes to work so it will know how wide the `RecyclerVIew` is. If that doesn't work, post your layout. Is the parent of the `RecyclerView` set to `wrap content` or `match_parent`?

Comment: @Cheticamp I did as you told.It didn't work.Added the xml file.

Comment: Try setting the width and height of the `ReyclerView` to `0dp` (`MATCH_CONSTRAINT`).  Not sure if this is your problem but from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#DimensionConstraints). _"Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to 'parent'. "_

Comment: Here is an example setup similar to what I think you are trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34581086/6287910 I still think it's a layout timing issue, but I can't put my finger on it. Maybe this example can help you figure it out.

Comment: @Cheticamp Setting up width and height of recycler view as 0dp worked.Thanks:)

Comment: I have also run into this issue and it seems to be a bug on Android side. I have filed an bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78613912

Answer (score 1):

Modified XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/editbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_floatedit"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```